# Populate and show winform using text file data from Background Thread

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Im writing an app in vb.net (Outlook VSTO ADDIN) where all of the functionalities are running in background thread and writes the output results in a text file during the background tasks/loops, Finally when the bg thread reaches the `RunWorkerCompleted` it suppose to call a new winform `Form1` where this new winform's job is to read the updated text file and show data. this works fine for the first time the bg thread runs by showing the accurate data in `Form1`. but when the same bg task runs in a scheduler periodically the `Form1` shows the old data which was shown the during the initial run.

For testing when I call the `Form1` from a button click event it shows the updated data from text file every time. But when the `Form1` called from background thread periodically in scheduler it does read the updated file but shows the old data which was shown in the first bg thread call.

```
Shared Form1 As New Form1

Public Shared Sub BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
  'some other codes
  Form1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
  LoadData()
End Sub

Public Sub LoadData()
  If File.Exists(FilePath..) Then
    'Read the file, process the data and show 
  End If
End Sub
```

.

## Update

I've tried following `InvokeRequired` as suggested and now `Form1` is showing the updated data each time. But there is another problem Im facing which was existed before as well. Sometimes the `Form1` got hanged on load and parent application (Outlook2013) stays unresponsive. I couldn't seem to find any solution for this hanging issue

```
If Form1.InvokeRequired Then
   Form1.Invoke(Sub()
        Form1.LoadData()
        End Sub)
   Form1.Show()
Else
   Form1.Show() : Form1.LoadData()
End If
```

Comment: If the data file is read when the Form loads and you're loading it only once... Since `LoadData()` is already `public`, you could call it directly after `Form1.Show()` (removing the call from `Form.Load`), so it's executed each time.

Comment: BTW, `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` it's a bad idea per se. Here, it appears to also have no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Threading in a WinForm in VSTO add-in requires both the threaded operation to get the data, but also a check that the form is available for updating. Below is older code using delegates from an old Excel VSTO add-in that received messages from a service, and depending on the state of the foreground, invoke the update.

```
    private delegate void StatusMessage();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Simple methods for setting active cube list before connecting
    /// </summary>
    private void SetDefaultNode()
    {
        if (this.ActiveCubeStatus.InvokeRequired)
        {
            StatusMessage d = new StatusMessage(SetDefaultNodeDirect);
            this.Invoke(d);
        }
        else
        {
            SetDefaultNodeDirect();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Simple methods for setting active cube list before connecting
    /// </summary>
    private void SetDefaultNodeDirect()
    {
        //clears treeveiw
        ClearActiveCubes();

        //create default inactive node
        TreeNode nodeDefault = new TreeNode();
        nodeDefault.Name = "Waiting";
        nodeDefault.Text = "Waiting on connection...";
        this.ActiveCubeStatus.Nodes.Add(nodeDefault);
        nodeDefault = null;
    }
```

BTW, I have some newer code using async operations; I will see if I can dig that up.

Comment: I've updated the question after your suggestion , could you please check

Comment: Wondering, if you can use the same syntax for the invoke. I would try several things, 1 - move the code Form1.Show() : Form1.LoadData() into it's own method, and then use that new method for both sections of the If..Else statement. If not that, I would try and isolate the cause of the problem, by temporarily removing the LoadData from both, and see if that always works. If yes, then it would seem there are issues within the LoadData method.